# Performance of passing a pointer to a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, global

I'm passing a pointer to a pointer to a `function x`, I do some processing with that pointer and then I free the value on `function y`

```
int x(char **str) {
    /* do some processing */
    return 0;
}

int y () {
    char *str;
    x (&str);
    /* do some processing */
    free (str);
}
```

However, I have noticed that if I declare `str` as `global`, then the time the program takes to complete everything, is less than actually passing `str` around. One it takes `135 secs, and 139 secs` (including all processing not coded above)

So, I was wondering why does passing a pointer to a pointer is perhaps 'substantially' slower than using the global approach.

Note: I tested several times, giving me the same results mentioned above.

Thanks

Comment: How did you measure the running time of this program?  Did you average the performance of a large number of runs?  Have you profiled the code to see that it is this particular change causing the performance decrease (if there actually is a performance decrease...)?

Comment: The global means the program has less work to do, but it is unlikely to be significant if you're doing any other significant processing in x, even if called in a loop. Did you compile with optimisation on? Otherwise, it's pretty pointless talking about performance. You're doing malloc/free is both versions you're benchmarking?  Also, the difference is small enough that it could be due to other things running on the PC, scheduling variations etc.. If you rerun half a dozen times, are the results consistent?

Comment: using `time` I was able to measure the running time. Averages are, 135 secs, and 139 secs, the variation was minimal, (~1 sec) on about 10 runs. This was the only change on the code. Also, could it be because I ran them on top of valgrind?

Comment: Without valgrind, the time it takes is about 5 secs both (avg), so in this case, the difference is not noticeable. @Tony: No, I did not compile with optimization.

Comment: @Jeff: Of course it was because you ran them on top of valgrind. You don't measure performance with stuff attached to your code.

Comment: @Jeff: Well, there's your problem. Without optimization, the compiler won't even *try* to emit fast code. In particular, every time you touch a variable, it will write it out to memory, rather than just keep it in registers. That's to simplify debugging, but it can have a huge cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm curious to see how you did your timings, because generally a double indirection shouldn't cost this much more than a single indirection — the difference should be tiny.

However, *if* your double pointer does cost more than a single one in this case, there are two probable reasons why:

(1) [Pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28computing%29) latency.

Modern CPUs are designed in such a way that while they can perform (at least) one instruction every cycle, most instructions take more than one cycle to complete. That is to say, you could *start* one new "add" operation every clock cycle, but the results of any given add might not be available until, say, four cycles after you start it. If you try to use the result of an operation before it's ready, it causes something called a [data hazard](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/dataHaz.html), which simply means that the processor has to wait until the result is ready before it can do something else with it. In your case, the computer has to perform two "load" operations in sequence, with assembly something like:

```
load r3, str  ; load the value of "str" (an address of a pointer) into register three
load r4, r3   ; load the thing at the address stored in r3 and put it in r4. 
              ; in this case, r3 points at a char *, so the thing in r4 is also an address.
load r5, r4   ; load the thing at address r4 and put it in r5. that is your char.
```

In this case, you can see that the third load depends on the result of the second load, which depends on the first. If the second load takes more than one cycle to complete (which it almost always does -- usually five cycles is about the best-case latency), then the third load must wait. There will be a "bubble" in the pipeline. If str is a global, then you have one less load, and thus one less bubble.

(2) [Data cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)

Modern memory is so huge, and CPUs are so fast, that accessing main RAM from the CPU can take many, many cycles. To speed this up, CPUs store a smaller subset of main memory locally in a cache, because if you use variable *x*, it's pretty likely that you are going to use *x* or something near *x* again. Accessing the cache is fast, but it only stores a small amount of data — usually something between 256kb and 4mb, generally. If a load operation tries to access an address that is not in the cache, then the CPU must go all the way to main RAM to fetch it, and the load operation can take 1000 cycles instead of just five.

So, if accessing **str means two cache misses instead of one, then the difference can be significant.

Ulrich Drepper wrote a very nice explanation of all these issues in his paper [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).